# Odd stopWatch result in Haskell

Tags: haskell, stopwatch

The [clock](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clock-0.7.2/docs/System-Clock.html#t:TimeSpec) package contains a **stopWatch** function that returns a TimeSpec record. It has a single constructor with two fields: sec (seconds) and nsec (nanoseconds). However, running this command gives an odd result:

```
TimeSpec {sec = 29, nsec = 656841598}
```

It does't look like nsec actually refers to nanoseconds since 1 sec should be 10^9 nanosec. Is this a bug in the library or is something else happening?

Comment: Looks like a fractional to me. 29 seconds + 656841598 nanoseconds.

Comment: Are you claiming the nsec part is greater than 1e9?  Well... `656841598 / 1e9 = 0.656841598`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sec` and `nsec` fields do not show the same thing expressed in different units, but *parts* of the whole time. That is, `{ sec = 1, nsec = 2 }` means "*1 second and 2 nanoseconds*".

Try this out:

```
print $ fromNanoSecs 1234567890000

> TimeSpec {sec = 1234, nsec = 567890000}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `TimeSpec` divided into two parts, a second counter and a nanosecond counter for second fractions. If you want the total time in nanoseconds, use [toNanoSecs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clock-0.7.2/docs/System-Clock.html#v:toNanoSecs).